# Why are the top latest questions are all concerned about the appropriateness of the question?

Tags: support, questions

The list of questions I see today is testament of it:

- Does this board cover questions on airport and airline operations?
- What is the standard of evidence required in answers?
- Why was my question closed?
- Is experience an opinion?
- Are model airplanes on topic here?
- Are questions about underwater search equipment suitable?
- Aren't these two duplicate?
- Would “recommend me an aircraft for this mission” questions be appropriate?

Comment: This is the aviation Meta site - where it's entirely appropriate to spend a lot of time trying to decide what is right for the main aviation site to discuss. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: When I see that half of all questions are about the appropriateness of a question and forum post policies, and why questions are closed (usually by the same 5 people), I know this site has to some deep retrospective about what success looks like and what isn't working.

Comment: it's not uncommon for a beta site to work out it's kinks this way

Comment: "beta" is an excuse. The forum is up for many months now. Questions are regularly closed by the same handful of people, not by the community. If I have to read posting policies first, and analyze my question, whether it can only have one answer, then I guarantee you this forum will fail, because won't bother. For example, I am planning a x-country trip and like to know good stop over airports for lunch. It's certainly aviation related, but it has not just one answer. If such a question is not appropriate, this forum's usefulness is vastly diminished.

Comment: One important note: this is ___not___ a forum. If this site _becomes_ a forum, Stack Exchange _will_ shut it down. If you want to discuss something like that, you can do so in chat, or on an aviation forum where that would be appropriate. The purpose of the Q&A site is to answer questions in a factual way, not to discuss your favorite place to eat.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but this is not a forum; it's a Q&A site. That said, you should probably just try asking your question. You point out that beta is "an excuse", but you're wrong – if you feel strongly that something is appropriate for the site, and you can explain why, then I for one will value your input and fight to make sure your voice is heard. The only way to make sure that the "same five people" don't make all the decisions is to get involved yourself.

Comment: The fact that it is **not** a forum, escaped me. Thank you for the clarification. This distinction is subtle for the majority of users, I would think, as is evident by the many policy questions. Also, purely fact based questions, say regulatory questions, can be easily looked up using your favorite search engine.

Comment: Actually, regulations can be exceedingly difficult to search for, and even when you find what seems to apply to your questions, there may be other laws or regulations or official interpretations which may change how it is applied. Asking on here may be a great way to quickly find out about something you may have missed or something you don't understand.

Comment: @AviationDude not all regulatory questions are straightforward google searches, and when you do search for those ones you might be surprised when the only useful link is back to this Q&A resource.

Answer (score 4):

One of the (many) points of Meta is to [*discuss the workings and policies of Aviation Stack Exchange … for people to ask how and why this site works the way it does*](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) -- In other words "deep retrospective about what success looks like and what [is and] isn't working" is exactly what we want here (so if that's what you're seeing in the posts here I think it means we're *Doing It Right*).

If you are concerned by the fact that "Questions are regularly closed by the same handful of people, not by the community" this is certainly the place to discuss that: Please go ahead and [open a "discussion" question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with questions that you think should have been left open/re-opened and we'll take a second look at them. (It generally works out best to have one post per disputed question to help focus the discussion.)
It's worth pointing out though that the same "handful of people" who are active in closing, editing, and re-opening are likely also the ones who read Meta, but we tend to be open-minded: it's always possible we've screwed up, or that a question can be improved rather than being closed.

---

In my opinion the Q&A model also tends to work best for questions with relatively static answers ([your fuel sender question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/952/can-resistive-fuel-senders-transducers-be-repaired-reconditioned) is a good example: there are two answers ("Find a specialty shop." or "Work with your mechanic.") and those are likely to be *the* answers for the foreseeable future.

"Where's a good place to stop off for lunch?" is an example going in the other direction -- airport restaurants can be somewhat ephemeral (the diner at KMGJ has changed owners/names a few times since I started my training), and the information goes stale quickly ([fly2lunch.com still lists the 56th Fighter Group at KFRG](http://www.fly2lunch.com/restaurant.php?rest_id=4536), but that's been closed for a long time).
For the "soft" topics (like picking stop-over airports for lunch on a long trip) [chat is probably a better fit than the main site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar). The audience isn't quite as large, but if more people use chat the audience will naturally expand (the same can be said for the main site).